# Ideas why this operational amplifier could have worse bias stability than anticipated

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-source, bias

### Background

Below is the simplified schematic of an operational amplifier I tested. I left out compensation components, because the question is about the DC behavior only. The design has sufficient phase margin of ~70° and doesn't oscillate. This circuit is built tightly on a ~2x1 cm two-layer board all in SMD.

The left column is two current sources and a resistor for biasing the input differential cascode (middle column). The output stage is formed using a [TL071H](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl071h.pdf) (CMOS version).

The bootstrapped cascode is an attempt to keep the input transistors always in the same environment. The goal of this design was to make both common-mode rejection ratio and input impedance "very high" in a voltage range leaving out the extremes close to the rails. Namely, based on extensive simulations (also using unmatched transistors!), I anticipated that **input offset (\$V_\text{IN+}-V_\text{IN-}\$) should change only ~10 µV when going across most of the input voltage range**.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKr5cT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### Problem

What I observed, however, was a several mV change of the input offset voltage \$V_\text{IN+}-V_\text{IN-}\$, rather linearly across input common-mode voltage, i.e. while varying \$V_\text{IN+}\$.

### Troubleshooting

I checked some voltages and found out a few things that worked well and others that deviated strongly from simulation:

- Node **A** stays firmly ~584 mV below the positive supply, so the top current source appears to be quite stable.
- The cascode bias voltage likewise is rather stable with only 1-2 mV of change across the input range.
- Node **B** changes strongly from 510 mV to 555 mV above the negative supply, indicating a strong change of the tail current. This was similarly stable to the top current source in the simulation. Q5 and Q6 are dual-packaged. Could it be that the heating of Q5 heats Q6 to cause such strong change? Could that also explain the comparatively low voltage drop? Using the thermal impedance of the package I estimate only 10 K max temp. rise even for the pass transistor Q5, so it sounds unlikely. Also, low input voltages should minimize the heat, but lead to the lowest voltage here of 510 mV, so opposite trend as expected for heating.
- Node **C** (TL071H bias) changes slightly from about 701 mV to 705 mV below the positive supply, which is in line with the previously observed varying tail current. But the surprising bit is that the offset between the two TL071H inputs changes by about 1.5 mV. I expected this to change only ~10 µV (output range divided by open-loop gain of TL071H).

**So do you have any ideas what could give rise to the last two issues in particular?**

Comment: In your simulation, was the offset already around 1mV and it only changed 10uV when you swept the input common-mode?

Comment: @ErnestoG The input offset voltage in the simulation strongly depends on the choice of the input transistor matching.. It could be up to several 100 mV (milli). But the change (i.e. CMRR) was in all cases very small (microvolts).

Comment: Ok, just for my own understanding, you sweep a DC voltage at IN+ and you find that there is, already, a large offset at the Op-amp terminals (let's say 100mV). Then, when you're sweeping, you find that this offset has a max and min (as a function of the DC input signal) that are separated by 1.5mV? Is that what's happening? In other words, your top current mirror collectors (Q1 & Q2) have a drain voltage error of a 100mV nominally?

Comment: @ErnestoG With "input offset voltage" I mean the voltage difference between `IN+` and `IN-`. The voltage at the TL071H terminals that I mention in my last bullet is merely a curiosity I noticed in my troubleshooting efforts. The voltage between the two TL071H terminals varies between about -100 µV and +1500 µV.

Comment: Just to eliminate the possibility- are you **100%** sure the real circuit was not oscillating during these measurements?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yes. I checked with the osci at several different input voltages. And I also checked if the offset reading changed when placing the osci probe onto and off the pins (to exclude any temporary stabilization of the circuit *by* the probes). The probes did not influence the measured DC offset. The DC voltages were measured with an isolated voltmeter in auto-zero mode. The circuit has on-board decoupling capacitors and was powered from batteries. The input voltage was generated on-board too, using a pot between the supplies.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany That being said, I also measured it with different compensation settings when it was indeed oscillating. I was also able to reproduce this oscillation behavior in the sims. For the compensation settings used for this DC test, both the sim and osci agree on the circuit having no oscillations.

Comment: @tobalt ah, ok. Well, I took a look at the op-amps datasheet and it says a 1mV DC offset can be expected. I know that's the absolute value and not the 1.5mV variation, but at least seems to be within spec.  About your Vin+ and - problem, can you also monitor the drains  of your input stage (just to discard the cascode). Are they the same voltage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today, I modified the circuit based on a discussion I had with Ernesto G. in another question a while ago. Namely, I removed the current mirror (Q1 and Q2) and replaced it with two 470 Ω resistors, one in each branch. So essentially, there are now 570 Ω total resistance from each of the TL071H inputs to the positive supply. It is now only the TL071H that keeps the currents mirrored.

This change has resolved both issues. Now, the input offset voltage of the total circuit seems to be pretty stable with respect to the common-mode voltage. It still drifts based on temperature (and temperature is a function of common-mode voltage), but this is a slow change which is ultimately irrelevant for my application.

Therefore, my explanation what happened in the original circuit is: the bottom current sink wasn't able to sink its full design current. Instead, the TL071H seems to have looked for its own equilibrium in a state where the combined current out of both mirror sides was lower than the designed sink current.

The main drawback of that "fix" is that it reduces the gain of the input stage and therefore makes the noise of the output stage op-amp more relevant. This is reason, why I went for a current-mirror in the first place. To be able to use a noisy cheapo TL071 as the output op-amp.

The simulations never suggested a problem with that initial circuit idea, and to be honest, I still don't understand why the "fix" works. I will make this the topic of a separate question eventually, if I can't figure it out myself.

Comment: Glad you could solve your issue @tobalt ! and your conclusion makes perfect sense. With regards to the noise, I'm sorry I couldn't be of any more help, in IC design, short of chopping, the best we can do is make the devices as wide to reduce noise. I'd say make a summary of your top contributors and try to work on them. Also, how much more is the TL071's noise made more relevant towards the input?

Comment: @ErnestoG Without the current mirror, the input stage gain is something like ~3 or so (pretty low), so the noise of the output opamp is suppressed only by a factor of ~3. With the current mirror, the stage gain was on the order of 50, so the noise of the opamp was essentially negligible. I will switch to JFET input transistors for noise reasons, which (modern ones) only really come in N-JFET flavor these days, so the output opamp must work close to the positive rail, hence the TL071. I am looking at folding the cascode now or making discrete output opamp next, to resolve these issues.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to clean solder flux.

The opamp is inside the feedback loop so its DC offset should be reduced by the high DC loop gain due to your transconductance input stage feeding its high impedance inputs. So I don't think the opamp is the culprit here. In order to rule it out, you can still try removing RL to avoid self-heating in the opamp output stage.

Next we have M1 and M2. There is the possibility that they are heated differently by nearby transistors, for example Q3 and Q4, maybe through the tracks. JFETs biased at the zero tempco point can give good stability versus ambient temperature, but the current required for this tends to be higher than you'd want.

> Node B changes strongly from 510 mV to 555 mV above the negative supply, indicating a strong change of the tail current. This was similarly stable to the top current source in the simulation. Q5 and Q6 are dual-packaged. Could it be that the heating of Q5 heats Q6 to cause such strong change?

These cheap dual transistors (BCM847, etc) have two chips in the same package but they are not mounted on the same metal leadframe. So while both transistors can heat each other, heat conduction occurs through the plastic material and not metal, so it is inefficient and slow. This is a problem if you want to use it in a circuit where the two devices temperatures need to track. Heat sinking through the pins into PCB copper will be different for both transistors due to them being connected to different tracks, and that is enough to overwhelm the weak heat transmission through the plastic. To get the same temperature in both devices, dissipation needs to be kept very low.

Here are three measurements, done while heating one transistor in the dual and measuring Vbe in the other at constant current:

[image]

[image]

[image]

At first sight this may not seem useful for your problem, but... notice the delay between the two curves. There is a time lag as heat flows through the plastic into the other chip. DMMT3904 has lower lag because the chip is smaller (faster to heat) ; DMMT5551 has a larger chip thus a longer lag.

If you can probe offset versus time after a variation in common mode you should see it settling after a delay similar to the curves above. You can confirm the current source is the problem by wiring a pot (or a pin header) in parallel with R3 and forcing a change in tail current equivalent to what you're observing, but without changing the common mode. If this results in the same output offset drift as with the common mode voltage change, then the current source looks guilty.

If offset takes much longer to settle, suspect components heating each other through the board. Also blow on it to check what happens with ambient temperature changes.

There can also be leakage current in your compensation caps, depending on type.

Comment: Thanks. I think cap leakage is unlikely, they are all Class I ceramics, and only the one around the TL071H has appreciable voltage, so might slightly decrease the opamp gain. I will conduct some heating tests as you suggested, but as I wrote in the question edit, the trend is actually opposite than expected due to heating. Do you have another hypothesis, even if far-fetched ? ;) And of course thanks, for such rare data 

Comment: Oops, I had missed the change going in the wrong direction. That can't happen, so the explanation is probably something that "everyone knows can't happen" ;) Maybe Q5 is starved of base current, R6 wrong value? I really think you need to look at settling of voltage on R3 on a scope with 0.1Hz square wave as Q5 Vce (common mode of your LTP). There's no cap or anything on the current source to slow down settling, so if it settles in microseconds, it's not thermal. Can you post a scope shot?